# How to swap domain in any URL in C#

Tags: c#, url

We have this issue of aggregating a bunch of URLs from multiple locations (multiple backend services) and returning them back to a caller. However, most of these URLs in truth are accessible from a common domain and we need to alter all of the URLs so they reflect that.

In other words, if I have these urls:

```
https://example.org/some/sub/path
http://123.example.net:798/and/yet/another?with=some%20params
https://wrong.again.it?id=1
```

We need a good algorithm to change the domains of each of those URLs so they all come from the same source and end up like so:

```
https://my.domain.net/some/sub/path
http://my.domain.net/and/yet/another?with=some%20params
https://my.domain.net?id=1
```

We haven't found a satisfactory way that is clean, elegant and efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly prototypical use for `UriBuilder`:

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://foo/bar?baz");
builder.Host = "newhost";
Console.WriteLine(builder.Uri);
```

There are corresponding `Scheme` and `Port` properties for remapping those as well.